# Rejected twice from iOS app store for crash on startup, but can't repro?

Tags: ios, iphone, marmalade

I've written an app using a cross platform SDK (Marmalade) and I have been able to publish a similar app there before. However, after two submissions, the app has been rejected twice for crashing upon startup - something that I cannot repro at all.

I've tested my code loads (especially after the first rejection), and though I don't have an iphone handy, I have sent the signed .ipa to testers to try it for me and they also can't repro the crash (they had to resign, but I doubt this is an issue).

The only major different between my other Marmalade app and this one was the other one was uploaded before arch64 was a requirement. Still, I'm creating builds with ARM + arch64 support. Still, I don't understand why the crash is only being reproduced by the signed distribution version by the Apple team.

I've attached the logs they gave me as I cannot decipher them at all. Specifically:

EXC_BAD_ACCESS

KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS

I've searched online, but it seems to be a pretty mixed bag of solutions, so I have no idea whats up. I've also attached the .ipa I uploaded. Any assistance would be appreciated!

Log: http://pastebin.com/muYSRCHF

ipa: https://www.sendspace.com/file/1s5l4a

Thanks.

Comment: ipa file cannot uncompress, maybe you should upload again.

Comment: you can't uncompress it? i just tried it using 7zip. whats up? i uploaded the .zip for you too if you get time to try: https://www.sendspace.com/file/jo2vd8 thanks!

Comment: still can't, Im using the Unachiver on Mac. Perheps somebody else could try uncompress it.

Comment: Did you test it on real ARM64 hardware with all supported os versions? Did you symbolicate the crash log and look what went wrong?